# A java runtime error with a native JNI static method for C++ implementation

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have a repo with [two simple implementations](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example) for JNI with C/C++.
I have the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` error for C++ static JNI method.

```
(base) GlushenkovYuri:java y.glushenkov$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.library.path=. MyJNIExample
Hello World from C!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: MyJNIExample.sayHelloCpp()V
        at MyJNIExample.sayHelloCpp(Native Method)
        at MyJNIExample.main(MyJNIExample.java:51)
```

But for C native method the same approach work well.
For C++ works without `static`.

You can reproduce the same behaviour in the following way:
1) Uncomment lines with [the static native method for C++](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.java#L51) and [this one](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.java#L56). And comment lines with [the NON static native method for C++](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.java#L50) and [this one](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.java#L55);
2) And just perform the next steps described in my [README.md](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example) file;

Can somebody explain to me why the native method static/non static works for C, but only the native NON static method works for C++?

UPD: my [header](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.h) file

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class MyJNIExample */

#ifndef _Included_MyJNIExample
#define _Included_MyJNIExample
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     MyJNIExample
 * Method:    sayHelloC
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNIExample_sayHelloC
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     MyJNIExample
 * Method:    sayHelloCpp
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNIExample_sayHelloCpp
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Post the generated header files so that people don't have to generate them themselves. Note that a static native method will receive a `jclass` as its second argument, not a `jobject`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on MacOS 10.14.6 with Java 1.8.0_66. Did you accidentally make the C++ function in the .cpp file `static` as well? That will hide it from the linker.

Comment: Or did you leave off the `extern "C"` tag?

Comment: @Michael I've updated my repo, I added the header file.
https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.h

Comment: @Botje No, I did. My .cpp file the same, as in my repo.
 https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the function that `javah` generates differs according to whether the `native` method is `static` or not:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNIExample_sayHelloCppstatic
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNIExample_sayHelloCppnonstatic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

In addition, the generated header contains an `extern "C"` declaration to make sure the compiler keeps the name intact of mangling it like `__Z29Java_MyJNIExample_sayHelloCppP7JNIEnv_P8_jobject`.

So, what happened here is that you generated a header file with a `static native void sayHelloCpp`, so there is an `extern "C"` declaration for the function with signature `(JNIEnv *, jclass)`, but you **provide** a `(JNIEnv *, jobject)` function. The compiler uses its default mangling scheme as the signature does not match, and the Java runtime fails to find it.

So, long story short: **always** regenerate your header file and check C++ function signatures if you change your Java class. I could not reproduce your issue because I wrote a Makefile that always regenerated the header file after recompiling the Java file.

Comment: Of course I regenerate my header, when I change my java file.
I have jclass in my signature, as u can [see](https://github.com/Arxemond777/JNI_C_CPP_example/blob/master/src/main/java/MyJNIExample.h#L23).
```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNIExample_sayHelloCpp
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

Comment: But your CPP file still mentions `jobject`, so the signatures don't match.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks.
But then I wonder why it works for .c and with jclass and with jobject? Why .c with jobject works as static and jclass works as NON static? Is the same difference in the semantic of this between C and C++?

Comment: Name mangling is a C++-only feature, as C does not have function or method overloading.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for this explanation!